# imagez load-image-resource complains "no implementation of method: :as-image"

Tags: clojure

On my Mac using `[net.mikera/imagez "0.12.0"]` when I run the example code to load an image I get an exception:

`user> (def ant (load-image-resource "mikera/image/samples/Ant.png"))
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :as-image of protocol: #'mikera.image.protocols/ImageResource found for class: nil, compiling:(form-init214709365644880775.clj:59:16)`

I'm running this code from within a Leiningen/Luminus project.

Perhaps I'm missing some dependencies for working with images?

My java version:

`java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you are using is using the clojure function `resource` to load the image.  Because the file `Ant.png` is not on the resource path, the call to `resource` is returning `nil`, which is why you're seeing this message. So, you need to add the path to your images as follows, in your `project.clj`:

```
:resource-paths ["/full/path/to/mikera/image/samples"]
```

Then in your code, reference the file as:

```
(def ant (load-image-resource "Ant.png"))
```

Comment: That makes sense, I was trying initially to load from an absolute path (my Desktop) which didn't work either. When I put the image into my existing resources/public/img it works :)

Answer (score 2):

To fix create a directory called `resources`. It will be a sibling of a directory you probably already have `src`. Put your file "Ant.png" in this directory. Then you could simply have this:

```
(def ant (load-image-resource "Ant.png"))
```